# Vagrant error while mounting nfs shared folders following roots bedrock+trellis+sage tutorial

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, nfs

Im following this repo https://github.com/roots/roots-example-project.com.
I did all steps till the vargrant up to see the development part.
It gives me this error after a few seconds:

> ==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required... sudo: /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server: command not
> found
>
> ==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders... The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means
> the command failed!
>
> mount -o 'vers=3,udp'
> 192.168.50.1:'/home/miguelrebola/projects/work/example.com/site' /vagrant-nfs-roots-example-project.com
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> stdin: is not a tty mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport
> protocol is not supported

I need to get that going and i've tried everything i found on internet.
It only gives this error once after that it only shows this when running vagrant up.

> --- work/example.com » vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>
> ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
>
> ==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.
>
> ==> default: Checking for host entries
>
> --- work/example.com »

any idea whats happening?

PS. Im on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `nfsd` is not running on your host machine (ubuntu does not install by default, mac os does)

install with `sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`

most probably it will be enough, if not follow the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo to setup everything.

*Second option* : if you do not want to setup nfs, you can remove `, type: 'nfs'` from the Vagrantfile and let vagrant use the default sharing folder mechanism.

Comment: I still had an issue here. Removing the type from the Vagrantfile does appear to allow the box to build. I honestly don't know about NFS -- Am I screwing myself by not doing this? Is it just slower?